# Collection.find returns less results when fields: {field: 1} is applied

Tags: meteor

I am trying to filter the data I send to the client.

```
characterFields = {
    _id: 1
    userId: 1
}

Meteor.publish 'nearbyCharacters', ->
    Characters.find({}, fields: {characterFields} )
```

However, when I include the fields: in the find method, it returns less results that if i do

```
Meteor.publish 'currentCharacter', ->
    Characters.find()
```

which returns the correct data, although not filtered

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get it so it only displays the _id field, be sure to leave the first param empty since its used for the query (which i'm assuming is all records, right?):

```
Meteor.publish "currentCharacter", ->
  Characters.find {},
    fields: characterFields
```

Comment: that helped somewhat, but i still limit the number of results when applying the fields attribute, when instead i want to return all records with selected attributes (UPDATED ORIGINAL)

Comment: Could you update your post with what exactly you want. Is it that you want your docs to have only the _id field, or is it that you want all docs with `field : {_id: 1, userId: 1}` in them. e.g {`_id:"23ioj98a", fields: {userId: 1, _id: 1}` but not match `{_id:'fhsdkjhdk', fields: {userId: '2', _id: 2 } }`

Comment: i want all the docs in the query (empty here) to be returned with only the specified fields available. So it should return the _id and userId of all the characters

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not reproduce your issue.

I've created a bare meteor `0.9.0` project (with no autopublish) with the following js:

```coffescript
Characters = new Meteor.Collection("items")
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.subscribe "items", ->
    console.log Characters.find().fetch()
    return

if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.publish "items", ->
    Characters.find {},
      fields:
        userId: 1


  unless Characters.find().fetch().length
    Characters.insert userId: 1
    Characters.insert userIdNaN: 1
```

On the clientside both entries are listed as expected:

[image]

Therefore I suppose your problem might reside somewhere else, maybe related with multiple publishes of same collection, or multiple subscribes to the same publish.